# Create a view from a function which returns a refcursor

Tags: function, view, plsql

```
Function A(p_option number)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS 
   CUR_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 

IF P_OPTION = 3 THEN
OPEN CUR_1 FOR
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5,COL6,COL7
FROM
(SELECT
D.COL1,
A.COL2,
A.COL3,
trunc(A.COL4) COL4,
A.COL5,
(SELECT stc.COL6 FROM TABLE stc WHERE stc.COL1 = A.COL3) COL6,
A.COL7,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY A.COL2 ORDER BY A.COL10 DESC) NO
FROM 
TABLE1 A  ,TABLE2 C,TABLE3 D,TABLE4 E
WHERE A.COL11 = 'A'
AND A.COL2=D.COL1
AND A.COL3 = c.COL1
AND D.COL2=E.COL1)
WHERE NO <= 5;
ELSIF.......
END IF;
RETURN CUR_1;
END ;
```

FUNC OUTPUT:

COL1 ||COL2 ||COL3 ||COL4 ||COL5 ||COL6 ||COL7
   EY  || ER  || ET  || EA  || EF  || EJ  ||ES

I want to create a view using the above function .I don't know how to create. Kindly help me out .

my view (VW_A) should look like:

```
CREATE VIEW VW_A
AS 
SELECT T1.COL1,A(T2.OPTIONS) FROM TABLE1 T1,TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.COL1=T2.COL1
AND T2.OPTIONS=3;
```

T1.COL1 ||COL1 ||COL2 ||COL3 ||COL4 ||COL5 ||COL6 ||COL7

XXX  || EY  || ER  || ET  || EA  || EF  || EJ  ||ES

Comment: https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/using-a-pipelined-function-for-a-flexible-view/
Mayby here you will find what you looking for.

Comment: Is there anyother way without creating a table .

Comment: you may use global temporary tables like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747859/oracle-pl-sql-creating-tables-in-cursor